# Android DrawerLayout + Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, drawerlayout

I'm currently struggling with creating an app using the new [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).

I've got the example up and running together with ActionBarSherlock. 
All the basics work just fine.

In my main page, i'm using tabs and as [Actionbar tabs are not advised](https://plus.google.com/u/1/116515063230772720916/posts/8dWEkFcbTFX) i'm using [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) as tabs with a ViewPager.

My problem however arrises when handling navigation with the navigation drawer. 
I'll have pages with simply 1 Fragment (like the Google example) and multiple pages with different Tabs (with the ViewPager).

What would be a smart approach to set this up? I'm having problems switching between a page with tabs and a page with just 1 fragment  and forsee problems with multiple pager adaters when i add more pages that use tabs..

Does anyone perhaps have a bit more extended example of the new DrawerLayout being used in combination with multiple different screens and not just 1 Fragment that switches a text or imageview.

TL;DR: Basically I need a way to switch the 'content-frame' with more then just 1 simple Fragment, without it becomming some huge hassle

Comment: Why aren't these separate activities, with the nav drawer clicks simply triggering `startActivity()`?

Comment: Because they don't seem to be separate activities anywhere anymore in the Google apps. If you look at Google Music and Google Play, the actionbar never  refreshes. They only switch fragments all the time, while opening a new Activity would look more like when you open the Settings of those apps

Comment: So, each nav drawer entry points to a fragment, perhaps containing nested fragments (e.g., your `ViewPager` scenario), and you `replace()` the top-level fragment on a nav drawer entry click.

Comment: hmm never worked with nested fragments. Will see how far that approach gets me, thnx

Comment: Note that nested fragments requires Android 4.2 or the current Android Support package's backport of fragments. Since you're using ABS, you'll be wanting the backport -- just make sure you (and ABS) are on the latest-and-greatest support JAR.